# Oracle SQL where clause does not work for some dates

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

Below query works fine with the recent dates (for e.g. if the date is 20-JUN-16, 30-SEP-19). But if I query with date value set to 29-MAR-80, 01-JAN-94 it does not return any result. Wondering what could be the reason. Am not allowed to change the existing year format to YYYY.
We are on Oracle 19c.

```
select * from V_IV_MUC where TRUNC(VALUE_TIMESTAMP) = '01-FEB-80';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your date `'01-FEB-80'` will be converted to `'01-FEB-1980'`, if your two digit year format is `RR`(in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`) and it will be converted to `'01-FEB-2080'` if your date format is set to `YY`(in `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`).

- `YY` -- convert the year to current century year - `80 --> 2080`
- `RR` -- convert the year to the year based on current year (1950-2049) so `80 --> 1980`.

You can use any of the following two queries to avoid any such dependencies on database settings.

```
-- use date literal
select * from V_IV_MUC where TRUNC(VALUE_TIMESTAMP) = date '1980-02-01';

-- use date string with format
select * from V_IV_MUC where TRUNC(VALUE_TIMESTAMP) = to_date('01-FEB-80','dd-mon-rr');
```